# Narrowing value type based on key type

Tags: typescript

I have types and the Save function below

```
type Collection<K extends string, EntityType> = {
  save(key: K, value: EntityType): void;
  get(key: K, value: EntityType): EntityType[];
  all(): EntityType[];
};

type Domain = {
  [key: string]: Collection<any, any>;
};

function Save<D extends Domain, K extends string, V>(
  dataStore: D,
  key: K,
  value: V
) {
  if (key.startsWith("orders/")) {
    dataStore.orders.save(key, value);
  } else if (key.startsWith("customers/")) {
    dataStore.customers.save(key, value);
  }
  //...
}
```

I want to use `Save()` like below. It should automatically narrow the value parameter type in `Save()` call to the corresponding entity type by looking up `Collection<>` members in `CommerceDomain`

```
type CustomerId = `customers/${string}`;
type OrderId = `orders/${string}`;
type ProductId = `products/${string}`;

interface Customer { customer: string }
interface Order { order: string }
interface Product { product: string }
declare const customer: Customer;
declare const order: Order;
declare const product: Product;

type CommerceDomain = {
  orders: Collection<OrderId, Order>;
  customers: Collection<CustomerId, Customer>;
  products: Collection<ProductId, Product>;
};

declare const store: CommerceDomain;

save(store, "orders/1", {/* should expect Order */});

save(store, "customers/1", {/* should expect Customer */});
```

Comment: Does [this approach](//tsplay.dev/wRAvvW) meet your needs? Note that we can't assume that `key` is a `string` inside `save` (or is it `Save`)? since `K` in `Collection` isn't required to be a `string`. Anyway, if that approach meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate unmet use cases, and while you're at it, make sure the code is a [mre] without problems you don't have (e.g., undeclared types/values, the `key` thing, typos, etc).  Let me know how to proceed.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz We could actually assume it can be a string. https://tsplay.dev/m3V1AN Apparently it provides better inference in this way. Your example was a good starting point. Thank you. Please post it as an answer I will accept! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to make `save()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) only in `D`, the type of the `dataStore` parameter, and in `K`, the type of the `key` parameter, and then compute the type of the `value` parameter from `D` and `K`.  We will also want to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to be applicable to `D`.  To that end, let's create some utility types.  `DomainKey<D>` will be the constraint for `K` and thus `key`, and then `DomainKeyValue<D, K>` will be the associated type for `value`:

```
type DomainKey<D extends Domain> =
  { [P in keyof D]-?: D[P] extends Collection<infer K, any> ? K : never }[keyof D]

type DomainKeyValue<D extends Domain, K extends DomainKey<D>> =
  { [P in keyof D]-?: D[P] extends Collection<K, infer V> ? V : never }[keyof D]
```

These are both *distributive object types* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If you have a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keylike types `KU` = `K1 | K2 | K3` and want to distribute a type function `F<>` over it to get `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`, you can do it like `{[P in KU]: F<P>}[KU]`, which creates a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [indexes into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

In our case our union of keylike types is `keyof D`, and the type function we want to apply to each key `P` of that union is `D[P] extends Collection<infer K, any> ? K : never` in the case of `DomainKey` and `D[P] extends Collection<K, infer V> ? V : never` in the case of `DomainKeyValue`.  These are both using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract the appropriate `K` and `V` type arguments out of `Collection<K, V>`.

Let's test those to make sure it works:

```
type TestDomain = {
  a: Collection<"foo", string>;
  b: Collection<"bar", number>;
  c: Collection<"baz", boolean>
}
type TestK = DomainKey<TestDomain>
// type TestK = "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
type TestV = DomainKeyValue<TestDomain, "bar">
// type TestV = number
```

Looks good.  Conceptually `save()` would therefore look like

```
function save<D extends Domain, K extends DomainKey<D>>(
  dataStore: D,
  key: K,
  value: DomainKeyValue<D, K>
) { /* impl */ }
```

And this does work, but unfortunately the IntelliSense only shows the utility type name `DomainKey<CommerceDomain>` for the type of `key`, which might not help the user:

```
// save(
//  dataStore: CommerceDomain, 
//  key: DomainKey<CommerceDomain>, // 
//  value: DomainKeyValue<CommerceDomain, DomainKey<CommerceDomain>>
// ): void
```

So we can use a trick to ask the compiler to expand it out, by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `K` with some specific supertype like `string` so that the compiler decides to evaluate it fully, showing something more useful:

```
function save<D extends Domain, K extends DomainKey<D>>(
  dataStore: D,
  key: K & string, // 
  value: DomainKeyValue<D, K> 
) { /* impl */ }

// save(
//  dataStore: CommerceDomain, 
//  key: `orders/${string}` | `customers/${string}` | `products/${string}`, // 
//  value: DomainKeyValue<CommerceDomain, DomainKey<CommerceDomain>>
// ): void
```

---

Okay let's see if it works on the example from the question:

```
save(store, 'orders/1', order); // okay
save(store, 'customers/1', customer); // okay
save(store, 'customers/1', product); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~~
// 'Product' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Customer'.
save(store, 'products/1', product); // okay
```

Looks good!  The inputs are constrained as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgHgNJQQAewEWAJgM5SXABO6WA5gDRQBqAfFALxQDeAKCg0AhgDcIACgDWEEAC4oeNuNEIArhCXsAlEvFx05ANzCoTCMFnylKqGs3aO+jgG0AumZHqEU1+yeZgC+ZoKgkFAAInAAtqKMvALmbnKKNPSMTB5K8EioGNg4olggbCUgnCFhEdAx8Yx48jhRhCRkVNFxCVjcPOb8UG4AClCJaXAAZtEeALQA-EpRIx5tpBTUechomLiMkxB0yuWl3PPKUEpYEJJHwanyUzOC4eB13Y3y7OpaLWsd1HqPTYBGI606QM+IBanD6AyGo3Gj2mUTmi2iK3+G1giG2hVw9n2hw4Zw4lyg11uUHuExRHher0iABUILRIVgkkIfLlcQVdjgAESTOBwAVsWgMZhVcwAIx5+R2RQFMtEdDFFI0sRlh2lIhQ8rx-OVogAXuqZSLkCVOIJgozoCzaAQ+OymtDHcB2TaAPTeqC1KAe51QIUigVQAA+IZVasj0dNAvtgdZwHYSVdXx+EBwHvZbGNap9foDHrTfCwmu1dBekw0WEVHMoEmzrTBAK6DSwIKxEI+WDdMM4UnM5FEwFEAGVgHA6M4oixzGk7FAAGQZSWscyOLRLPtu75OFog7iCXTJF4idDTGwgAB0tFVwEoAHV0MAABZSAUz8iHSjegVdDPLkRCgUdxynGcIFvH8-3vZsb1ULNdG8alCAQShoCvKAb3vcc6CfV8Py-FANFoOI-wAoDklAsCx0nadZ1vUjyNiOCm0kRCHGQ1C7REX1b0El47STGAyOnNi6AASXIJIAAMWIkyiABJ+AlLJgjkswAwAeToX9pNkvg5Nguh-1U9TmE07S3igYY6DgcgNDQGT5LABynLQcy1MyKytJeRhSDoSZRBQaAxNY4lBkUii6CUSymGpQRAsOEKwqgPSDIEKBTPi3zErtFLgtC6B7Mc5zgGy9zyrQPKNyS38UAQVVoBQbBaCgGLJNycTYrMRrmtnTr2sq3KMv0w5+tQQbWpGqBqs84AlDKxaals+BYkksL2U5cxTMoA0+SKTLDhktgTroXVOt6ySDpxBV8RwCKlMMthntiq6Foqu6tiO3AVoqs67I8irpVCF4Bpa4asA68jZx5TbDm2vswg46Q4YgNgAHJ9u9ABGLG2FMlCoF9HKZFEEBBDRqQMexrrKIJtgGboEmybgCmqZpumoCxln-yZ+aQbQNm-UOBy6AAQkEMnZjl+WFcVpXZm4AA-dWNdVmW-SxgG0CxsZqCwOBKtEShKHQJgsFEGVkH9OB5tVUQ2KCnLpgDLH3skrHb2phCeaxr6vPxwmhZq4BRfJynBCAA)

Comment: That's an awesome answer! Thank you.